# Find Value in JSON using python

Tags: python, json

I have json file contains : 
.
How can I return the only results for agent_id  394903921554

```
enter code here
```

{
    "agent_timeline": [{
            "agent_id": 394903921554,
            "engagement_count": 0,
            "start_time": "2020-06-15T06:00:00.000000Z",
            "status": "invisible",
            "duration": 901.929878
        },
        {
            "agent_id": 397330457313,
            "engagement_count": 0,
            "start_time": "2020-06-15T06:00:00.000000Z",
            "status": "invisible",
            "duration": 901.929878
        },
        {
            "agent_id": 401565578994,
            "engagement_count": 0,
            "start_time": "2020-06-15T06:00:00.000000Z",
            "status": "invisible",
            "duration": 4.664595
        },
        {
            "agent_id": 394903921554,
            "engagement_count": 0,
            "start_time": "2020-06-15T06:00:11.000000Z",
            "status": "online",
            "duration": 901.929878
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Your `json` looks incorrect. Is it list of `dict`?

Comment: I have corrected the code , please check it again :)

Comment: I posted the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I assume in the file, the out-most bracket is square bracket (`[]`), otherwise it's not a valid json file.

You can read with:

```
import json
with open(FILENAME, "r") as f: 
    r = json.load(f)
```

Then, you will get a list of json objects. From there you can just do a simple filter to get the info you want:

```
result = [x for x in r if x["agent_id"] == 394903921554]
result = result[0] if result else None
```

The last line will take care of the case when agent_id is not in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you assign the full `json` result to a variable named `results` then you can filter it simply as following.

```
filtered = filter(lambda x: x['agent_id'] == 394903921554, results)
for item in filtered:
    print(item)
```

This will give you a generator.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that structure is an array in the format of:

```
x = [
 {
    "agent_id": 394903921554,
    "engagement_count": 0,
    "start_time": "2020-06-15T06:00:00.000000Z",
    "status": "invisible",
    "duration": 901.929878
},
{
    "agent_id": 397330457313,
    "engagement_count": 0,
    "start_time": "2020-06-15T06:00:00.000000Z",
    "status": "invisible",
    "duration": 901.929878
},
{
    "agent_id": 401565578994,
    "engagement_count": 0,
    "start_time": "2020-06-15T06:00:00.000000Z",
    "status": "invisible",
    "duration": 4.664595
},
{
    "agent_id": 394903921554,
    "engagement_count": 0,
    "start_time": "2020-06-15T06:00:11.000000Z",
    "status": "online",
    "duration": 901.929878
    }
 ]
```

You could do the following:

```
[item for item in x if item['agent_id'] == 394903921554]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json

# load json from file, and covert to a Python object, in this case, a list of dictionaries
with open('my_file.json') as fp:
  lst = json.load(fp)

# use built-in filter() method to filter the list
matches = filter(lambda o: o["agent_id"] == 394903921554, lst)

# grab your dictionary
obj = next(matches)
```

Note that your text is not a valid json - assuming it is a list, it should be surrounded by '[]'